# What's the correct way to delete all future occurrences of a Realm object?

Tags: swift, for-loop, realm, crud

Currently, I am using this code to delete all future repeat transactions:

```
let futureRecurringTransactions = self.transactions.filter(NSPredicate(format: "transactionDescription == %@ && transactionDate >= %@ && transactionCategory == %@", transaction!.transactionDescription!, transaction!.transactionDate as CVarArg, transaction!.transactionCategory!))
            
            for transaction in futureRecurringTransactions {
                try! self.realm.write {
                    self.realm.delete(transaction)
                }
            }
```

Here is my Realm data model:

```
import RealmSwift

class Transaction: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var transactionDescription: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var transactionAmount = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var transactionDate = Date()
    @objc dynamic var transactionCategory: Category? = nil
    @objc dynamic var repeatInterval = ""
    @objc dynamic var isCleared = false
    @objc dynamic var transactionName = ""
    @objc dynamic var transactionID = UUID().uuidString
    
    convenience init(theDate: Date) {
        self.init()
        self.transactionDate = theDate
    }
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "transactionID"
    }
        
}
```

The code works, but it feels like the way I'm doing it is amateur and clunky. Is there a better way that is more accurate and proper?

I thought it might be good to utilize the transactionID , but each transaction has a unique transactionID, so I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Instead of running code like that over and over and deleting potential duplicates, why not just prevent a duplicate from being written in the first place? When the data is entered, query for it to see if there's a match and if so, prevent the write. That would save a lot of cpu cycles and hitting the database repeatedly on a regular basis

Comment: I don't understand, what duplicates are you referring to @Jay?

Comment: I was referring to what was asked in the question *all future repeat transactions* a repeat transaction would be a 'duplicate'.

Comment: Ah, I meant a repeat transaction that happens every month or every week. Not duplicates, but recurring transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I typically do is create a unique NSPredicate for each constraint you want to place on the collection. You can mix and match each predicate to form a unique set of filters. For example:

```
extension NSPredicate {
    static func transactionDescriptionEqualTo(_ description: String?) -> NSPredicate {
        if let description = description {
            return .init(format: "transactionDescription == %@", description)
        }
        return .init(format: "transactionDescription == nil")
    }

    static func transactionCategoryEqualTo(_ category: Category?) -> NSPredicate {
        if let category = category {
            return .init(format: "transactionCategory == %@", category)
        }
        return .init(format: "transactionCategory == nil")
    }

    static func transactionDateIsAfter(_ date: Date) -> NSPredicate {
        return .init(format: "transactionDate >= %@", date as NSDate)
    }

    static func transactionIDNotEqualTo(_ id: String) -> NSPredicate {
        return .init(format: "transactionID != %@", id)
    }

    static func futureRepeats(of transaction: Transaction) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
            .transactionDescriptionEqualTo(transaction.transactionDescription),
            .transactionCategoryEqualTo(transaction.transactionCategory),
            .transactionDateIsAfter(transaction.transactionDate),
            .transactionIDNotEqualTo(transaction.transactionID),
        ])
    }
}
```

Also note that you don't need to loop over the results. You can delete all objects in the results like this:

```
let realm = try Realm()
try realm.write {
    realm.delete(transactions.filter(.futureRepeats(of: transaction)))
}
```

Lastly, it's a good idea to include the transactionID as a constraint. Otherwise the original transaction will be included in the results.