# How to create an "edit all future events" feature similar to Apple's calendar

Tags: swift, for-loop, filter, properties, realm

Apple's calendar has a feature when you delete (or edit) a repeat event:

"Do you want to delete (or edit) this and all future occurrences of this event, or only the selected occurrence?"

I'm using Realm in my project.

My guess is that one would go about this by creating a for-loop to filter and then update each item:

```
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let filteredItems = realm.objects(Item).filter(someUniqueFilter)
        let newValue = *something*
        for item in filteredItems {
            realm.write {
                item.value = newValue
            }
        }
```

If I'm on the right path, what is a strong "someUniqueFilter" property you can give an Item object that is unique for each repeating Item series?

Or is there another way to do this that I'm not realizing?

Thank you.

Comment: You asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518594/whats-the-correct-way-to-delete-all-future-occurrences-of-a-realm-object) recently and it has an accepted answer. Can you use that answer for this question? The results returned from deleting all future transactions would be the same as the results for editing all future transactions. Borrowing from their answer `let results = transactions.filter(.futureRepeats(of: transaction))`

Comment: You're right Jay, it is a similar question. But this question is asking how to create a unique property that can be stored for a series of repeat items. If the user edits one item (like the name or description), then it will be skipped in that filter. I want to know how to create a property that the user can't edit that is unique for that series. In Apple's calendar, you can edit all of the properties on an event, but there is still something telling it that those events are still linked in that series.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the question here; if you look at the functionality in Apple Calendar, if you select a single event and change the name, it gives you two options 1) Change all future events (so they are still all linked, repeating events) or Only this event, which actually creates an entirely new event and replaces the repeating event in that slot. If you were to alter an event and make it Only This Event its then no longer part of the series and would not show up in queries.